# jquery event handler for different element on different action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery , in my project i have  same action for form submit and for hyperlink click event. Code is same for both action , but i need to write separate event handler  as follows

`$("#elem1").click( //do some action  )`   and

```
  $("#form1").submit(//do some action )
```

can we write mixed event handler for both in one line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) to call the other event's code:

```
$("#form1").submit(function() { /* do some action */ } );
$("#elem1").click(function() { $('#form1').trigger('submit'); } );
```

However, if `#elem1` *is* the submit button for `#form1`, you don't need to do this, as it will run the code twice in a row.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a function and pass it as a reference to your handlers:

```
function myHandler(event) {
  //do some action
};

$('#elem1').on('click', myHandler);
$('#form1').on('submit', myHandler);
```

Comment: can also modify selector to include both elements: `$('#elem1, #form1').on('click', myHandler);`

Comment: That wouldn't work unless you wanted to trigger the handler every time the form was clicked. It would be possible to write a single handler for `$('#elem1, #form1').on('click submit', myHandler);`, but your handler would need to check if the event were a click and which element was clicked, which would be much more complicated that the two lines above.